# Looking for C++ #ifdef eliminator like 'coan' but that can work within expressions too

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

We have tons of legacy code with "feature bits", where you can toggle a feature at runtime, like

```
if (GET_FEATURE ("foo")) {
   // foo foo things
}

or

if (!GET_FEATURE ("bar")) {
   // do "non-bar" things
}

or even

if (GET_FEATURE ("foo") && state->foo_might_apply ()) {
   // do foo things
}
```

I'd like to be able to run a filter and say "foo" is enabled, and get code like

```
// do foo things     ("if" test gone)

if (!GET_FEATURE ("bar")) {
    // do bar things  (this whole block untouched)
}

if (stat->foo_might_apply ()) {
    // do foo things  ("if" test simplified)
}
```

I know coan can do these kind of things for #ifdef blocks.  I want something that goes deeper into the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want a tool to permanently alter the source code based on certain features ?

Comment: Just a question: what is coan?

Comment: Raxvan.... yes.... I want and automated filter that could alter source for me.

Comment: @AdriC.S. http://coan2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Could you give a really "tight" definition of how to detect an active or non-active feature? I am thinking of offering an sed or perl based dedicated tool. For that I would need the typical pairs of sample input/desired output. Note that this only can work, if your sample input (or rules in prose) allow to identify the closing "}". That gets complicated incredibly fast, if the "// foo foo things" contain "{...}". It gets next-to-impossible if creative non-symmetric mixtures of "#if" and "{}" occur.